# QuickStart Tutorials for Rational Functional Tester (RFT)

Tags: rft

I am new to RFT. Infact I have seen the interface only once. But now my next project seems to be an automation using RFT. I would like to get some quick start on learning RFT(Rational Functional Tester).

Can anyone show me some quick links as to where can I start with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to first download RFT from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/r/rft/)

Once the installation is done, Click the Help tab, and then click Tutorials. That will be a good quick start IMO.

Then access the sample projects in RFT and it is Eclipse based, so if you have used Eclipse before, it will be fairly easy to pick up.

You could go in more detail later, and look up features like "keyword driven frameworks" etc for a real world example.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to IBM Release notes link where you can find Simple tutorials to get started with RFT.

Comment: Are you working for IBM/Rational? That sounds like an employee's answer.